# how to change a title of the activity?

Tags: android, textview, titlebar, page-title

How do I change the title of the activity? as of now it just displays the title of the program and i am wanting it to display something of my choosing and be different for each page/activity in my app i.e. my home page could say frog(1/17) in the title  while another activity that the app switches to could have frog(2/17) in that  title  by using on click event or by using butt

Comment: you can change it after going in manifest file... or just rename to it

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you would like something dynamic that changes the title (page count) when the button is pressed?

I would suggest the following:

```
private static int pageCount = 1; // global variable in class. Default page = 1

onCreate() {
setPage(pageCount); // Set the title for the first time

}

// When your button is clicked
private static onButton() {
pageCount++; // Increment page count by one
setPage(pageCount); // set the new title


}

private static setPage(int page) {
setTitle("frog(" + page + "/17)");

}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the title in code like this:

```
setTitle("Some Title");
```

You can also do it in xml like this:

```
android:label="Some Title"
android:label="@strings/someTitle"
```

Comment: as soon as i click on the button titles of the activities should change like frog (1/17);frog(2/17)

Comment: Then use the first example of setTitle("Some Title"); when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

you can find result in android sdk sample ApiDemos, in section App -> Activity -> Custom Title

Answer (score 0):

You change title of an Activity programmatically by following code:

```
getActionBar.setTitle("Your_Activity_Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

I just looked for the "values" folder inside the RES directory. There, you see a file named strings.xml.
Inside that file, you find the values for all the titles of the activities. Look for the activity you want to change and presto!
Example: The activity I wanted to change was "news" and the title I needed was "Here".
I found this value:
    Central

So I changed it to this:
    Here

It gave me no trouble.